# Apache Htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have to write a htaccess to rewrite the links as follows and also a redirection of 404
error pages to my sites root (home page)

```
www.example.com/index.php?page=find&name=detail&id=109&cid=8
www.example.com/index.php?page=find&name=detail&id=109
www.example.com/index.php?page=find&name=detail
www.example.com/index.php?page=find
```

should be rewritten to

```
www.example.com/find/name/detail/id/109/cid/8
www.example.com/find/name/detail/id/109
www.example.com/find/name/detail
www.example.com/find
```

Comment: If URL is `www.example.com/foobar` should it result in 404 or `www.example.com/index.php?page=foobar`?

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess rules,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/page/([a-zA-Z]+)/id/([0-9]+)/cid/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=find&name=detail&id=109&cid=8 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/page/([a-zA-Z]+)/id/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=find&name=detail&id=109 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/page/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ index.php?page=find&name=detail [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ index.php?page=find [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i also want page, id, cid these also to be as a variable. And a 404 error redirection to my home page.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^find$ index.php?page=find [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(find)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*)$ /$1$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
FallbackResource /
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/(.*)/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/(.*)/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/(.*)/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/(.*)\.html index.php?itfpage=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7$8=$9 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/(.*)/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/(.*)/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/(.*)\.html index.php?itfpage=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5&$6=$7 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/(.*)/([a-zA-z0-9]*)/(.*)\.html index.php?itfpage=$1&$2=$3&$4=$5 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/([a-zA-Z]*)/(.*)\.html index.php?itfpage=$1&$2=$3 [L]
```